# Comet implementation on glassfish v3

Tags: java, comet, glassfish-3

I am trying to implement comet grizzly on my glassfish server v3.

I am trying to connect web server from desktop application using http url object.

I am creating ObjectInputStreamer and ObjectOutputStreamer at both client and web server.

In webserver servlet I am creating ObjectOutputStream to write response back to client.
And this output streamer I am attaching to handling of comet so that I could push data to client without request on same response channel afterwards.

and on client I am not closing the InputStreamer so that I can read the response pushed by webserver using comet.

But on writing data on output stream from webserver it is not giving any exception but still I am not able to read at client end which gives EOFException on reading from opened Input Stream.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Comet is a technique used to notify a client of changes on the server over an http internet connection.  A good place to start learning comet are the examples [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/333664/906048)  Using the java.io.ObjectInput/OutputStream is for reading in files, passing serialized java objects, etc.  They use the [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html), which won't work with comet.